# Are owners of XIB must/should be UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, xib, subclassing

I have had success with UIView as owner when I want to subclass UIView with xib.

However, it's kind of awkward and involve moving all superView from self.view to self in initWith:something class.

That's the only function I override and it looks fine enough till now.

So, is owner designed to be only for UIViewController?

Can it be a subclass of UIView too?

What other classes are appropriate?

I am just curious, if there is some tutorial on how to more properly subclass UIView and use XIB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no restriction on which class can act as the File's Owner placeholder. [UINib](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) exists specifically to provide you with a way to load nib files with whichever owning object you need.

See the [object loading process](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19) for details.

Comment: Ah I see. WHen we load nib we got an array and we got the iboutlet of owners pointed to the right direction. So nib is essentially arrays of arrays of arrays...